# Get the index of a Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, search

I have a numpy array:

```
arr = [0.23, 2.32, 4.04, 5.02, 6.84, 10.12, 10.34, 11.93,12.44]
```

I want to get the index of the closest integer I enter.  For example if I enter 10 then I should get back index 5 (10.12) or if I enter 12 i should get back index 7 (11.93).

Comment: Is the array guaranteed to be sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list isn't sorted, you will need a linear time solution using `abs` + `argmin`:

```
>>> np.abs(np.array(arr) - 12).argmin()
7
```

However, if your list is sorted (ascending or descending), you can employ binary search for a sub-linear time solution (very fast):

```
# https://ideone.com/aKEpI2 — improved by @user2357112
def binary_search(arr, val):
    # val must be in the closed interval between arr[i-1] and arr[i],
    # unless one of i-1 or i is beyond the bounds of the array.
    i = np.searchsorted(arr, val)

    if i == 0:
        # Smaller than the smallest element
        return i
    elif i == len(arr):
        # Bigger than the biggest element
        return i - 1
    elif val - arr[i - 1] <= arr[i] - val:
        # At least as close to arr[i - 1] as arr[i]
        return i - 1

    # Closer to arr[i] than arr[i - 1]
    return i
```

```
cases = [10, 12, 100, 10.12]   # 5, 7, 8, 5
print(*[binary_search(arr, c) for c in cases], sep=',')
```

Comment: You  are a bit sloppy today, aren't you? The `searchsorted` soln gives the wrong answer for `10` (`4` instead of `5`).

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful with `searchsorted` if you want the nearest element. Particularly, searching for `0` returns `-1`, searching for `10.12` fails to report the index of `10.12`, and searching for a value between two values of the array always picks the index of the left value, even if the right value is closer.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Beg pardon, have been quite sleep deprived of late. Let me fix this, I'll make sure it works.

Comment: "have been quite sleep deprived" --- guessed as much ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer Done, let me know how it shapes up now.

Comment: @user2357112 I've done my best to address every issue you've listed... thanks a bunch.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: [Not quite right](https://ideone.com/FuEmM2). Your neighbor selection is considering the neighbor on the right and the element to the right of that, rather than the neighbor on the left and the neighbor on the right. Also, the `len(arr) - 1` special case is wrong.

Comment: I believe [this edited version](https://ideone.com/aKEpI2) should handle things, barring rounding error in the nearest-neighbor determination, but I'm not sure I'm running on enough sleep myself.

Comment: @user2357112 It does give the same answer as COLDSPEED's first solution for all of a huge number of test cases.

Comment: @user2357112 Updated my answer with your edited version, hope that's alright.